# How can i do python form post request?

Tags: python, forms, apache, post, request

`form.html`:

```
<form action="p.py" method="post">
 <input type="text" id="id_text" name="name_text" />
 <input type="submit" id="id_submit" name="name_submit" />
</form>
```

`p.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#what to write here...
```

Both files are put in `/var/www/` , now from http://example.com/form.html, if I click the submit button would I execute the `p.py`  and how can I get the value of textbox?

It's apache/httpd webserver installed on computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st**, to make `p.py` run by apache, you need to check:

- 1, config apache site for a python script, you may choose: cgi/fastcgi
- such as: *ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/local/xxxxxx/cgi-bin/*
- 2, make sure your `p.py` file is runable, modify by `chown`/`chmod`

**2nd**, to get the value from a form, you need to understand cgi knowleges and get data from environment,

or much easier by using cgi module:

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
v = form.getvalue('id_text','')

print """Content-type: text/html

<html>
<body> submit value:%s </body>
</html>""" % (v)
```

**at last**, I suggest:

- put runable scripts to a separated dir, away from `/var/www/`
- using a web framework for web develop. It's too deep to use cgi level technology in 2012.

Comment: No, i don't want to make a cgi app, rather i want to use wsgi app.

Comment: Dynamic Content must have a method to communicate with apache. you refuse CGI/WSGI, what u choose?

Comment: I refused CGI, i didn't refuse WSGI, actually i'm trying with WSGI.